# Почему бот Telegram отправляет сообщения с file_get_contents() но не делает то же самое c curl?

Tags: веб-программирование, telegram-bot, telegram, бот, curl

У меня настроен WebHook на сервере, чтобы он автоматически отвечал на сообщения пользователей в Telegram.

Когда я делаю в соответствие с примером из документации:

/index.php

```
$urlQuery = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" . $token . "/sendMessage?chat_id=". $chatId ."&text=" . $textMessage;

$result = file_get_contents($urlQuery);
```

все срабатывает.
Но когда я пытаюсь сделать то же самое CURL, то не пашет:

/index.php

```
$sendingToTelegram = $phones->makeRequest([$token,$chatId,$textMessage], 'apiTelegram');
```

/Parser.php

```
public function makeRequest(array $args, string $type)
    {
        if($type === "apiTelegram") {
                     
$website="https://api.telegram.org/bot".$args[0];

$params5=[
    'chat_id'=>$args[1],
    'text'=>$args[2],
];

$ch5 = curl_init($website . '/sendMessage');
curl_setopt($ch5, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch5, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch5, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch5, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ($params5));
curl_setopt($ch5, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$result5 = curl_exec($ch5);

curl_close($ch5);
return $result5;
        }
        
    }
```

Если воспользоваться функцией getWebhookInfo() для тестирования хука, то если чат отправляет sendMessage через file_get_contents, то результат такой:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А если в index.php, работает вышеописанный curl, то такой результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не ясно зачем нужно выкладвыть какие-то скрины заголовков ответов. Нужно как минимум сам ответ показывать...... А вообще, берёшь отладку и смотришь что у тебя приходит, какие статусы, какие ответы. какие ошибки

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701142/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-php-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)

Comment: Cамый главный вопрос: что плохого в `file_get_contents` ?